# Small caps for CM Sans with fontspec and sansmathfonts

Tags: fonts, fontspec, font-encodings, sansmathfonts, newcomputermodern

I wand to use NewCMSans from the `newcomputermodern` package because it provides a true bold sans (instead of a stroke-extension like `lm` or `cmu`, see the documentation of newcomputermodern). The NewCM fonts are available as OpenType only, so I need to use `fontspec`.

`NewCMSans` offers small caps in Regular and Oblique (optical size 8pt, not 10pt) but not in Bold or Bold Oblique.
The `sansmathfonts` package provides Sans Bold and Bold Slanted small caps but only as `Type 1` fonts. Is it possible to combine these small caps fonts (and oldstyle numbers) of sansmathfonts with the other fonts of NewCMSans for the main Sans font?

Hereafter is my attempt but I cannot force the font encoding to `T1` for the sansmathfonts within the fontspec definition of `\setsansfont`.

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
% lualatex and fontspec needed because New Computer Modern is only available as OpenType fonts
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{newcomputermodern}
\usepackage{sansmathfonts}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setsansfont{NewComputerModernSans10}[
Numbers=OldStyle,
ItalicFeatures = { SmallCapsFont = NewCMSans08-Oblique, SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps} },
BoldFeatures = { SmallCapsFont = cmssbxcsc10 },  % \usefont{T1}{xcmss}{bx}{sc}
BoldItalicFeatures = { SmallCapsFont = cmssxicsc10 },  % \usefont{T1}{xcmss}{bx}{scit}
]

\begin{document}

\sffamily
\begin{itemize}
  \item Upright éà 1234 and \textsc{Small Caps éà 1234},
  \item \emph{Italic éà 1234 and \textsc{Italic (Oblique) Small Caps éà 1234}},
  \item \textbf{Bold éà 1234 and \textsc{Bold Small Caps éà 1234}},
  \item \textbf{\emph{Bold Italic éà 1234 and \textsc{Bold Italic Small Caps éà 1234}}}.
\end{itemize}

Desired output (small caps with accents and oldstyle figures):
\usefont{T1}{xcmss}{bx}{sc}
Bold Small Caps éà \fontspec{LMSans10-Bold}[Numbers=OldStyle]1234
\usefont{T1}{xcmss}{bx}{scit}
Bold Italic Small Caps éà \fontspec{LMSans10-BoldOblique}[Numbers=OldStyle]1234

\end{document}
```

Comment: inputenc is not active so there is no standard way to map the unicode input to T1 encoding just in regions that are using a T1 encoded font, you could probably do something with a Lua callback but that is not provided. It will sort of half work by accident as T1 is not that different to latin 1 which is compatible with the initial codepoints in unicode, but any characters that are different in T1 will silently produce the wrong output if you use a T1 encoded font.

Comment: The NewCM fonts contain all the shapes you ask for. But currently the table mapping, say A to A.sc, is not there so you can not select them. I will add this table soon. As for oldstylenums you can select them enabling the onum feature.

Comment: Thank you very much for the comment David. I think the simplest and best thing would effectively be to be able to access small caps via the OpenType features defined correctly in NewComputerModernSans. I will wait for Antonis to fix these (thanks for the fonts and for this work). Then maybe I will put this in reply if others seek to have CM Sans-Serif small caps OpenType fonts. Many thanks to both of you.